# How to get parent GridView's data-bound value

Tags: asp.net, databound-controls, nested-repeater

```
<asp:GridView DataSource="Reports">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("ReportId") %>'
        <asp:Repeater DataSource="Something that is different than the GridView's DS">
            <a href='<%# Bind("ReportId", "reports.aspx?report={0}") %>'/>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

I know this is inachievable, I am looking for a way to use ReportId from the parent gridview in the nested repeater, is there a way to do it with server side code <%# %>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the gridview

```
DataKeyField="ReportId"
```

and in the event GridView1_ItemDataBound inside it

```
protected void GridView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewItemEventArgs e)    
((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")).text = GridView1.DataKeys[0].ToString();
```

and in this case u set the textbox with the value of the ID, try it and hope that it will be usefull.

Comment: As I specified, I am looking for a way to do it with <%# %>.
meanwhile i do it in the code by handling the Repeater's row databound event cehecking if current row is the Footer which works even better.

Comment: No execuse me i am sorry i don't know h to do that i will try seraching u the solution

Comment: Thanks for your help, I realized that it doesn't have to be in the repeater, I put it outside the repeater and that's it.
But I will still have such issues in future.